# no se imprimen los valores

Tags: array, bucle-for, matrices

quiero que la primera y ultima columna se intercambien valores pero el profe no nos enseño como :c
por eso no sabia como hacerlo lo hice asi pero no se si esta bien,quiero que me muestre la matriz original y la matriz intercambiada.

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
       //definimos una matriz
       int matriz[][];
       int Filas,Columnas;
       // Lectura de filas y columnas de la matriz
       Filas =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño de fila de la matriz : "));
       Columnas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño de columna de la matriz"));
       //creamos la matriz
       matriz= new int[Filas][Columnas];
       //lectura de los datos del vector
       for(int i=0; i<Filas; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<Columnas ; j++){
              matriz[i][j] =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese valor para la matriz["+i+"]["+j+"] :"));
           }
       }
       //generar una cadena con los datos de la matriz
       String cadena="";
       for(int i=0;i<Filas;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
               cadena =  cadena + "    "+matriz[i][j];
           }
           cadena=cadena+"\n";
       }
       //calculos
         for(int i=1;i<=Filas;i++){       //calculos
       int auxiliar;
       auxiliar=matriz[i][1];
       matriz[i][1]=matriz[i][Columnas];
       matriz[i][Columnas]=auxiliar;}
    
       


    }
}
```